# How to create a responsive square container?

Tags: css

[image]

How to create a responsive square container in which to place elements?

Comment: Using percent on the css sizes (width,height) of the elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `viewport` units

```css
div {
  width: 40vw;
  height: 40vw;
  background: black url(http://www.lorempixel.com/500/500/nature) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Or `percent`

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
div {
  width: 40%;
  height: 40%;
  background: black url(http://www.lorempixel.com/500/500/nature) center no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

And here is a post showing an `aspect ratio` solution: [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

You currently can't assign the same width to a html element as the height if you use %-s. You need to use javascript

```
var element = document.getElementById("your-element");
element.style.height = element.style.width;
//Note: you need to put after the style tags or you need to make it load after fhe document has been loaded
```